# What does Laravel 'find' method return

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

A simple MySQL table namely `centers` is out there with `Center` as its model and `code` as  one of the columns.

```
$center_found=Center::find(6);
echo " code from method 1 =  ".$center_found->code;
echo " code from method 1 =  ".$center_found['code'];
echo " type = ".gettype($center_found);
```

To my wonder both ways work to find out the `code` and the type shows to be `object`.

So 
1) what is the return type of `find` ?

2) Does the return type ever vary except when no matching result exists ?

Comment: Check this [Retrieving Single Models / Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) from document.

Comment: If `gettype($center_found)` returns `'object'`, use [`get_class($center_found)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) to find its class.

Comment: @axiac, `class` shows to be `App\Customer`. That does not answer question 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

`Model::find()` returns [either an instance of `Model` or a collection containing one or more instances of `Model`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models).

Comment: 2 questions are in the OP. What is the data type of the result ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_find

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: Either a model or a collection, just like the answer says.

Comment: @linktoahref, does that answer both of the questions 1 and 2 ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, is model or collection `object` or `array` ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed 1. Return type is model | Collection| Builder | null 2. return type is null when no matching result exist

Comment: @linktoahref, clarify whether that is `object` or `array` .

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed find would return model instance or collection which are objects

Comment: @linktoahref, then why does `$center_found['code']` work ?

Comment: Why do you believe that PHP objects can't emulate indexing?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed It may be because the Model implements the [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) interface

Comment: @linktoahref, so anytime the result from `find` can be accessed either as an objecct or an array , right ? I mean the result type will not vary unless it is NULL. Am I right ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: The "or" in the answer matters.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, in what way does it matter ? Clarify fully.